# Why do i get / How do i remove the ugly curly brackets? (Python3.9/Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, curly-braces

**Hi everyone!**

I don't really know anything about coding (as you can probably tell by my code), and I've somehow put together this random-picker with the help of way more YouTube videos than I'd like to admit to!

Now, I'm getting a very weird output and I have no clue why it is like this. Can anyone help?

In “liste.txt” are just multiple lines of “normal” text. (as I show in the video)

The output I'm getting: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scTapPU8Ens)

I want exactly this output, just without the curly brackets ("{}") and without the weird Ä/Ö/Ü formatting.

If you see anything else horribly wrong with my code, please let me know. I want to improve.

Thanks & Greetings from Switzerland!!

```
import random
from tkinter import *
import pygame


win=Tk()
win.geometry("1200x600")
win.title("RandomPickerSLF - by atefxf")


with open("liste.txt", "r") as f:
   liste = f.readlines()


Label(win, text="Wie viele Themen möchtest du haben?", font=('Calibri 12')).pack(pady=60)
a=Entry(win, width=35)
a.pack()
a.insert(0, "5")


pygame.mixer.init()


def anzeigen():
   t1=int(a.get())
   choice = random.choices(liste, k=(t1))
   label1.config(text=choice, font=('Calibri 13'))
   pygame.mixer.music.load("click1.wav")
   pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.3)
   pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)


label = Label(win, text="Deine Themen : ", font=('Calibri 15'))
label.pack(pady=10)


label1 = Label(win, text=" ", font=('Calibri 15'))
label1.pack(pady=20)


Button(win, text="Lasse dir deine Themen anzeigen!", command=anzeigen).pack(pady=90)


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you want to have `label1.config(text='\n'.join(choice), font='Calibri 13')` when defining the text of the label.

Comment: Yes! That's what it was! Although, it did not fix the problem with the Ä/Ö/Ü! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Ä/Ö/etc. is probably due to the file `liste.txt` not being encoded in UTF-8. If you find out which encoding it is, then [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) has an `encoding` parameter to specify it.

Comment: The file "liste.txt" is encoded in UTF-8. I just rechecked with notepad, using save as to check.

Comment: Is it a font issue then? Do you notice a pattern with special characters?

Comment: It seems to replace:

Ä - Ã¤  |
Ö - Ã¼  |
Ü - Ã¶  |
ß - ÄŸ  | I didn't notice anything else!

Comment: I was able to fix it by replacing "with open("liste.txt", "r") as f:" with "with open("liste.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:"! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you pass a list of strings with *trailing newline* to `text` option of `Label`.

Either strip out the newline:

```py
choice = [x.strip() for x in random.choices(liste, k=t1)]
```

or joining the strings into one string:

```py
choice = ''.join(random.choices(liste, k=t1))
```

Comment: I was able to fix the Bracket-Problem by putting

"label1.config(text='\n'.join(choice), font='Calibri 13')"


instead of 


"label1.config(text=choice, font=('Calibri 13'))"

Although, that did not fix the problem with the Ä/Ö/Ü! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @atefxf. Then try `open("liste.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")`.